# Identifying text variables in lists in vba

Tags: excel, vba, list, select

I've been trying, unsuccessfully, for weeks to create a macro that loops through rows of text and identifies variable text phrases to sort products by there underlying components. That text phrase will be located in different spots across the page or linked with multiple other variables. For example how many products in a list contain "leather" and identify that in an answer row next to the list with a defined phrase like "Absolutely". The code I've been working with looks like this:

```
Sub Find()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set Sheet = ActiveSheet
Set rng = Sheet.Range("E2:J7")

For Each row In rng.Rows
 For Each cell In row.Cells
   Select Case cell.Value
    Case "Oil"
    Case "Leather"
      Cells(row.row, 11).Value = "Absolutely"
    Case "Absolutely"
    Case "Nope"
    Case Else
      Cells(row.row, 11).Value = "Nope"
   End Select
  Next cell
 Next row

End Sub
```

And the Table would look look this:

[image: Table associated with code above]

Currently the code runs through the correct lines and sees all of the components but fails to identify the answers in the answer row. I'm using this code to hopefully identify many variable components in many product lists and "Leather" and "Oil" are currently just place holders. Hopefully this will help myself and many other people avoid reading long lists of data and marking individually whether or not each item meets a certain defined criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Does this have to be VBA?  You could easily do this with the [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34).  Using your provided sample data, in cell D10 use this formula and copy down:

```
=IF(C10="","",IF(COUNTIF($2:$7,C10)>0,"Absolutely","Nope"))
```

Comment: Yes because i need to use this code on multiple sheets with hundreds of products and 50+ underlying component variables. I've just been using two variables for simplicity's sake.